# Firebase v9 version of firebase.apps.length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

In a React application, I usually initialize firebase like this:

```js
if (firebase.apps.length < 1) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  // Initialize other firebase products here
}
```

This worked perfectly until I upgraded to v9 beta. How do I make it work for the new version?

Comment: On a note, you are no longer required to check if there's a default instance of Firebase already in the new SDK.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The correct way to do it is to use `getApps()`:

```js
import { getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

if (getApps().length < 1) {
  initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  // Initialize other firebase products here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution that has worked for me for v9 is this:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

let firebase;

if (!firebase) {
  firebase = initializeApp(config)
}
```

Comment: You are checking if `firebase` is false, undefined, or null. If it is any of those, why would the `initializeApp` function be defined?

Comment: Right, good catch. I jumbled v8 and 9 here. I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes. Also, you can just import the method you want to use without using the `firebase` constant at all.

Comment: I'm just exporting it for use in other files where I need it for getFunctions(), getAuth(), etc.